# Spring Security: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: spring, spring-security

I just equipped a simple Spring test project with basic authentication functionality. When the server is loaded I get the well-known error 
**org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined**.

`web.xml`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


  <!-- Activate Spring Security -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`servlet-context.xml` contains the security related configuration:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <sec:http auto-config='true'>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </sec:http>
    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <sec:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <context:component-scan base-package="myproject" />

</beans:beans>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The security config must be loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. Move the security related stuff to the `root-context.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to M. Deinum's comment I found out that I could just add the path of my servlet-context to the contextConfigLocation:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: You could but don't... You are basically now duplicating all the beans which might (and will) in the future lead to nice to debug weird errors. Not to mention your application is now taking up more memory then needed. So as stated move the security related stuff to the root-context.xml or a separate xml which you load but don't start loading config files twice...

Comment: servlet-context.xml file is already configured in appServlet servlet mapping. So no need to add it again as context param.